# generating a list with php, depending on button id and value

Tags: php, ajax

I'm new to web development and don't quite know everything I need. So I'm trying to generate a list with php from an xml file, when a button is clicked. The generation is dependant on the button's id and value.

Here is the php generating the list:

```
<?php

$art_c=$_REQUEST["art"];
$an_c=$_REQUEST["an"];
$fisier="arh.xml";
$xml=simplexml_load_file($fisier) or die("Unable to load XML file!");

foreach($xml->an as $an)
{
    if($an['anid']==$an_c)
    {
        foreach($an->nr as $nr)
        {
            if($nr['nrid']==$nr_c)
            {
                foreach($xml->articol as $art)
                {
                    $univ = array();
                    $aut = array('','','','','','','','','','');
                    $articol=trim($art).".xml";
                    $xmlart=simplexml_load_file($articol) or die("Unable to load XML file!");

                    echo '<html> <body><div id="special">Title:&nbsp</div></body></html>';
                    echo "<a href=".trim($art).".php".">";
                    $tit=$xmlart->titlu;
                    echo "$tit</a>";
                    echo "<br/>";
                    echo '<html> <body><div id="special">Autori:&nbsp</div></body></html>';

                    foreach($xmlart->autor as $autor)
                    {
                        $idx=$autor['univ'];
                        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($univ);$i++)
                        {
                            if(strcmp($univ[$i],$idx)==0)break;
                        }
                        if($i>=sizeof($univ))
                        {
                            $univ[$i]=$idx;
                        }
                        if(strlen($aut[$i])==0)$aut[$i]=$autor;
                        else $aut[$i]=$aut[$i].', '.$autor;
                    }

                    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($univ);$i++)
                    {
                        echo $aut[$i].' - '.$univ[$i];
                        echo "<br/>";
                        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }


}

echo "<br/>";
```

I tried dending the id adn value with ajax, but the php does not get the variables I send with ajax.

A model of the xml file is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<rev>
  <an anid="2014">
    <nr nrid="1" data="27 martie">
      <articol>
        <titlu>titlu1</titlu> 
        <autor univ="UAIC">Ionescu</autor> 
        <autor univ="UMF">Cata</autor> 
        <autor univ="UMF">Stan</autor> 
        <autor univ="UAIC">Alex</autor> 
        <autor univ="UAIC">Dan</autor> 
        <tag>tag1,tag2,tag3</tag> 
        <id>2014_1_1</id> 
      </articol>
```

Any idea how could I do this?

Comment: What is your javascript to make the ajax call ?

Comment: function cuprins(art, an)
{
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("art").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("an").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","cuprins.php?art&an",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request is not correct, you didn't set the values for "art" and "an", it should be something like "cuprins.php?art=xxx&an=yyy"